# Почему при сохранении CSV файла появился дополнительный столбец перед данными?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

почему при чтении CSV файла и его редактирования с последующим сохранением через -

```
df.to_csv("df.csv")
```

я получаю это
[image: пример]
  почему добавилась дополнительная нумерация и запятая перед первым заголовком?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По умолчанию метод [df.to_csv(..., index=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) сохраняет значения индекса. Чтобы этого избежать надо явно указать:

```
df.to_csv(..., index=False)
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо!!